# Date range according to month in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well i am trying to display a date range in the container header on click of button.ON the click of the button it takes the value of it and displays it.

```
var date = new Date,day = date.getDate(),month = date.getMonth() + 1,                   
year = date.getFullYear(),hour = date.getHours(),minute = date.getMinutes(),
seconds = date.getSeconds(),ampm = hour > 12 ? "PM" : "AM";

hour = hour % 12;
hour = hour ? hour : 12; 

minute = minute > 9 ? minute : "0" + minute;
seconds = seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
hour = hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour;


date = month + "/" + (day-6) + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + " " + ampm + " - " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + " " + ampm;
// date holds in the format "12/16/2011 08:14 PM"
$('#panelid').text(date); //panelid is where date range will be shown
```

As i was working on this code after 10th i didn't face this problem but now day range becomes something like 
this : 2/-5/2014 11:51 AM - 2/1/2014 11:51 AM

How can i remedy this? Any suggestion.

Comment: your (day-6)  is the problem

Comment: Chek out the date-object from JavaScript -  it has all functions included:http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/date.htm

Comment: You can convert it into an unix-timestamp, subtract the needed amount of seconds, and convert it back

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format